# To update cache values in iis using powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

am trying to update cache values in IIS , using below powershell script but couldn't helping to get exact output. can some one help me to correct this.

[image]

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter "/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache" -name cacheControlMode -value "UseExpires"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter "/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache" -name cacheControlMaxAge -value "02:00:00"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter "/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache" -name httpExpires -value "Tue, 20 Feb 2020 00:00:00 GMT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PowerShell object notation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/set-webconfiguration?view=winserver2012-ps). You may need to close and open IIS Manager to see the changes. Below is the way it worked for me

```
Set-WebConfiguration `
    -PSPath IIS:\Sites\Default\<your web application> `
    -filter '/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache' -Value (@{cacheControlCustom=""})
```